# Laravel Testing with assertTrue method error on simple test

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

Im trying to do a real simple test going with Laravel 4 but getting errors.

Here is my super simple test.

```
class SignupTest extends TestCase {
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->call('GET', '/');
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

Error Stack Trace

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method SignupTest::assertTrue() in /home/domain/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php on line 135
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/domain/vendor/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/domain/vendor/bin/phpunit:63
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:783
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:838
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
PHP  12. SignupTest->testIndex() /home/domain/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
PHP  13. Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->assertResponseOk() /home/domain/app/tests/Unit/Controllers/SignupTest.php:9
```

You can see I'm extending the TestCase so I should have access to the assertTrue method.

Composer Part Incase it help.s

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "way/laravel-test-helpers": "dev-master",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "dev-master",
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev"
},
```

I have dumped autoload and cleared compiled.

Hope you can advise.

Comment: What's on line 9 of SignupTest?

Comment: The assertTrue method:  $this->assertResponseOk();

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `app/tests` folder, full `SignupTest` class, and `composer.json` autoload section?

Comment: The app/tests folder just holds the class you see above and the TestCase file created by Laravel. And the SignupTest is everything above, I have added the require-dev composer part above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the phpunit was an old version and I had to re-install all vendor files.